# Modify LWC component styles

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I came across a requirement where I wanted to change the width of the Date & Time pickers of the

```
<lightning-input></lightning-input>
```

LWC component from component library. It took some time for me to figure out I might not be able to set the styles of items within an LWC component because of the Shadow DOM restrictions.

Is there any easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [DOM Access Containment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_dom) it is supposed to behave like that. There is nothing to ***fix*** there.

I would suggest to use 2 inputs for your use-case and restrict widths on them.

Sample code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-input class="data-input" type="date" name="input1" label="date"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input class="time-input" type="time" name="input1" label="time"></lightning-input>
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
.data-input {
    width: 5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
.time-input {
    width: 10rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.